# ImageAdapter onClick goes wrong

Tags: java, android, image, view, adapter

I'm trying to set an onClick listener on my ImageView in the Adapter of my GridView. However, weird thing happens: The content of the onClick function affects also some other Views in my GridView.

There is a good reason that I don't do the click listener on my GridView, so I need a solution for this via the ImageAdapter.
The logcat is called only once I click, but for some reason, other ImageViews are affected by this function.

Here's relevant code:

```
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       final ViewHolder holder;
       if(convertView == null) {
           holder = new ViewHolder();
           convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_multiphoto_item, null);
          holder.tickImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tickImageView);
          holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
          holder.imageViewLayout = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewLayout);
           convertView.setTag(holder);
       }
       else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
       }

       holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)v;
    int id = imageView.getId();
    imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);/*
    if(!thumbnailsselection[id]){
        Log.d(Global.TAG, "CLICK");

        holder.tickImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.imageViewLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imageview_selected);
        thumbnailsselection[id] = true;
    }
    else{
        holder.tickImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.imageViewLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imageview_unselected);
        thumbnailsselection[id] = false;
    }
    */
}
```

});

```
           holder.imageView.setId(position);
           holder.imageViewLayout.setId(position);
           holder.tickImageView.setId(position);
           holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(thumbnails[position]);

   return convertView;
  }

        class ViewHolder {
            ImageView imageView;
            LinearLayout imageViewLayout;
            ImageView tickImageView;
            int id;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In baseAdapters, view are recycled. This means that if you set a view to invisible, you will add some other view invisible when you will scroll.
To avoid that, be sure to set again the visibility of yout view in the getView method:

```
holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnCl...
```

Also you will have to store each visibility state, in order to reassing to visible or invisible.

Comment: Great, works! Thank you very much. Though, I still don't understand why other views get affected when setting to invisible :)

Comment: because, when a view goes out of the screen when scrolling it's not destroyed. Adpater will resuse it when the scrollView will ask for a new view. it's the view named convertView. So, if you don't change the visibility or the content in it, it will be the old view that will be displayed.

Comment: BTW, it means that it's not that efficient now, because it always creates new views and doesn't recycle, right?

Comment: No, you still recycle your view. The only thing is that you set visibility of its child every draw, but it's not really a problem. The main subject of recycling is to avoid creating a lot of view and avoid to call findViewById each time.